# daterangepicker not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, daterangepicker

I am implementing [daterange picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) in my page. But it is not working. Could somebody please point out what am I doing wrong or What is that I am missing.

CSHTML:

```
<div class="has-feedback" >
    <input type="text" id="txtDateRange"
           class="form-control input-md" name="RangeDates"
           placeholder="Select Range"
           ng-model="Model.RageDates">
    <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <span style="color: #a94442" >
        <label class="control-label" class="has-error" ng-show="RangeDates.$invalid">Required.</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

js :

```
DashBoardModule.controller('DashBoardController', ['$scope','$filter', 'DashBoardModuleService', function ($scope,$filter, DashBoardModuleService) {

   $('#txtDateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $scope.isRefreshing = true;
        $scope.Model.introductoryPeriodEnd = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.endDate), dateFormat);
        $scope.Model.introductoryPeriodStart = $filter('date')(new Date(picker.startDate), dateFormat);
        $scope.Model.typeAvailability = picker.chosenLabel === "Custom Range" ? "Custom" : picker.chosenLabel;
        $scope.$apply();    
    });

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var dateConfiguration = new Date();
        $('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker({
            ranges: {
                'Next Week': [new Date(), dateConfiguration.setDate(dateConfiguration.getDate() + 6)],
                'Next 2 Weeks': [new Date(), dateConfiguration.setDate(dateConfiguration.getDate() + 8)]
            },
            format: dateFormat,
            autoApply: true
        });
    });    
}]);
```

_Layout :

```
 <!-- Range Date Picker -->
 <link href="~/Scripts/Controls/DateRangePicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/Controls/DateRangePicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should probably include a link to the date range picker API you are using. Also what does `not working` mean? What is happening that should not or not happening that should?

Comment: the date picker window is not poping up.

Comment: Again, if you want help with an API please post a link to that API. If you Google `daterangepicker` you will see there are many possible APIs to choose from. I do not think it is realistic that those who would like to help have to guess which particular API you need help with.

Comment: I am not using any API.  I was following hte http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: That's an API. It is a 3rd party control/component that you program against.

Comment: Do you have the required referenced libraries as stated in tho documentation in your `_Layout`? Do you have any errors that appear in the browser console?

Comment: Ya I am referencing all the required libraries and I don't see any errors in the console.

Comment: When you debug your javascript code and run through it with breakpoints, do you enter your document ready function defined in angular when the page loads? How many elements are found with the jquery function `$('#txtDateRange')` in that block? My guess is that having that defined in the controller itself could be the problem as the controller might initialize after the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not answering your question. Because I prefer advice you: AVOID IT.

What you are doing is not the Angular Way. You are working in the jQuery Way. So, will be harder to you to use Angular and Libs. So, you have 2 choices: use AngularJS or use jQuery.

Why you are not doing in Angular way:

0 - With Angular you shouldn't use jQuery to select elements. (you are using with the `$('#txtDateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker',` and  `angular.element(document).ready` and `$('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker`

Take care of this. Or Angular will be harder and not elegant.

If you prefer to use angular, you can use an ANGULAR Date Picker, Please check this: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers

I hope it can help you!